# How to detect if any program is using microphone

Tags: windows, windows-10, microphone

Is there anyway on Windows 10 to detect when a program access the microphone?

I'm looking to create a sort of On-Air light using a smart bulb in my office. So I'm looking for a programmatic way to access this information.

Comment: A microphone icon is displayed in the traybar when the mic is active. This isn't guaranteed to work for older programs.

Comment: @harrymc I've seen that but I'm looking for a programatic way to access that information

Comment: Programming question are more suitable for stackoverflow.com.

Comment: It would be a duplicate question on stackoverflow.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559542/detecting-if-the-microphone-is-on.  I hope you have some programming chops.  It looks like you will need to use COM to get the information.

Comment: You may check these two posts to see if they can give you some helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61661373/is-there-an-api-to-check-if-macs-microphone-or-video-camera-is-in-use     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63032108/see-if-an-app-is-using-the-microphone-on-windows-10